# How to handle a Data error from Data Grid View

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I am receiving an exception from dataGridView when I load a ComboBox's Column with class objects with overloaded `ToString()` methods.

I have tried everything that I can find on the internet to prevent this error, and I had another open question on SO trying to sort this one out also, however I was unsuccessful.

The most straightforward answer I received, was to handle the error message, and prevent it from loading, to this extent I have googled around, and created this method that I believe should resolve the issue.

```
private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
{
    anError.Cancel = true;
}
```

Its a bit crude, but I believe it should work, however when I add a breakpoint, the error still persists, and never breaks into this function. I have never done anything with error handling before, and it is very likely I am missing something.

Thoughts?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18814/A-method-that-provides-how-to-handle-events-when-m  will help you

Comment: You dont need to do anything, leave that even handle empty and it will ignore the error. I've had this before where there are no errors.

Comment: Just tried what Derek suggested. It hasn't worked. I have that event handler function inside class Form1, is it meant to be somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this...

```
private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Error happened " + anError.Context.ToString());
    
    if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Commit error");
    }
    if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Cell change");
    }
    if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("parsing error");
    }
    if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("leave control error");
    }
    if ((anError.Exception) is ConstraintException)
    {
        DataGridView view = (DataGridView)sender;
        view.Rows[anError.RowIndex].ErrorText = "an error"; view.Rows[anError.RowIndex].Cells[anError.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "an  error";
        anError.ThrowException = false;
    }
}
```

Read this link : [DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerroreventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'd suggest doing something like this `if (anError.Context.HasFlag(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing)) {...}` since DataGridViewDataErrorContexts enum is a flag-type enum and not always contains only certain value

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was simple after all.

```
private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
```

Needed to be renamed.

```
private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
```

Capital D ladies and gentlemen.

Thanks for all the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You must insert a line code in your project at the file "YourForm.Designer.cs"

```
    this.dataGridView1.DataError += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_DataError);
```

before add this method into file "YourForm.cs"

```
    private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error happened " + anError.Context.ToString());
    }
```